# Erro na autenticação ao integrar Facebook SDK 3.6 ao Android

Tags: android, facebook

Estou tendo dificuldades para integrar o Facebook SDK 3.6 ao Android.
Ao tentar logar no app, aparece o seguinte erro:

> Invalid Android Key parameter

Como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Este erro acontece porque a chave que está tentando acessar a sdk do Facebook não está registrada no *console* do aplicação (Facebook).

Para que o login funcione, você precisa gerar o *hash* das *keystores* de debug e das *keystore* de produção.

Uma explicação mais detalhada pode ser encontrada nesse [link](http://www.devmedia.com.br/integrando-aplicacoes-android-com-o-facebook/27567) (http://www.devmedia.com.br/integrando-aplicacoes-android-com-o-facebook/27567).

Mas, um pequeno conselho:
O *keytool* no Windows pode apresentar falhas bem chatas na geração dessa *hash* (falo isso com conhecimento de causa)! Caso tenha problemas para gerar, você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
try{ logger.debug("Checking signs");
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        logger.debug(Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    logger.debug(e.getMessage());
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    logger.debug(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Amigo, onde coloco esse código por favor, detalhe pra mim por gentileza. Desculpe, pois sou leigo ainda no assunto. Muito grato pela sua atenção.

Comment: Consegui gerar, agora não encontro o local para colocar lá no painel de controle do app no facebook!!!

Comment: Entre na pagina de _developer_ do Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/apps) e vá até o app que você criou. Em seguida, clique em opções (para editar as informações do app). Lá, terá uma seção "Android" e um campo para inserção da hash. No link que eu postei na resposta tem uma imagem desse processo.

Comment: Igor, consegui, mas mesmo assim dá o erro de chave incompatível, no erro dá que a chave não corresponde com a mesma.